# User email from GitHub in django social login

Tags: python, django, github-api, django-socialauth

I followed this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) to get social login in my django application.
It is working well, but for github users I can't get user email, even when I add

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SCOPE = ['email']
```

What should I change in the article example to get user email?

Comment: how about `['user:email']`?

Comment: Yes! Write this as an answer, not comment, so I'll mark it as a solution

Comment: if you are using `django-allauth`
then try 
```SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {'github': {'SCOPE': ['user','repo','user:email',],}}```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please change to:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SCOPE = ['user:email']
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!